# Copying content of one class to another

Tags: java, serialization

I have a map:

```
Map<String, List<ClassA>> X
```

Where `class A` is serializable.

and another map

```
Map<String, List<ClassB>> Y
```

Where `class B` is not serializable.

Content of both `Class A` and `Class B` are same.

Now I want to copy `map X` to `map Y` but I cant do it directly by assigning because Classes are different.

So I thought to extend `Class B` to `Class A` by just adding `extends Class B` in `Class A`.

But then also I am not able to copy the `Map X` to `Map Y` since parent can not be assigned to child so I thought of casting but since it map I am not able to think of casting.

Any suggestions that how can I make both class compatible?

P.S.: Here I don't want to extend since extending is not a proper method.

Answer (score 1):

You can use method `putAll()` from `java.util.Map`, [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#putAll%28java.util.Map%29).

```
void putAll(Map<? extends K, ? extends V> m);
```

> Copies all of the mappings from the specified map to this map (optional operation).

In your scenario:

```
Y.putAll(X);
```